# Comparing timestamps and working with timezones on iOS

Tags: ios, swift

Given a unix timestamp, how can my iOS code know if it is before or after 6am (6am = the most recent 6am that occurred)? Are there time zones involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the unix timestamp to a `Date`. Then use `Calendar` to get the `DateComponents` from the `Date`. By default, these components will be interpreted in the user's current timezone. If you wish to interpret the date in a different timezone, set the calendar's timezone before getting the components from the date.

By looking at the desired components you can make your decision about the hour.

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: someUnixTimeStamp)
let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents(in: TimeZone.current, from: date)
// look at hour as needed
```

There are other `Calendar` APIs if you just want a single component or just a smaller subset of components instead of all components from the date.